# How do I escape the single quote in Rythm?

Tags: rythm

getAddress()

```
output: Test&apos;Street&apos;Address
```

There are multiple templates that need to be addressed. Please do let me know in case if there is an option configure at one place that fixes all templates.

Any ideas/suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are in either JavaScript or JSON region, in which case Rythm automatically escapesthe variable output using JavaScript escaping.

If you need the literal output, please use `.raw()` transformer. E.g. you change `@myVar.getAddress()` into `@myVar.getAddress().raw()`

For more information about escaping, please refer to http://rythmengine.org/doc/expression.md#escape